# AngularJs: using ngBindHtml with static content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-bind-html

I'm having static content inside ng-bind-html like this

```
<div ng-bind-html="htmlContent">
  <div>Static HTML</div>
</div>
```

but when I'm updating the model inside controller, the content is replaced. But I want the content to be appended. Can anyone tell how to achieve this.

Please refer to the following link:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q4kvx76z/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Inside HTML : Added button

```
<button ng-click='updateHtml()'>
   One Click  
</button>
```

Inside Controller : create function as 'updateHtml'

```
$scope.updateHtml = function (){
    // Get current Html Content 
    var currentHtmlContent = $scope.htmlContent;
    // Add new content to currentHtmlContent 
    $scope.htmlContent = currentHtmlContent + 
    $sce.trustAsHtml("<div> New Content </div>"); 
}
```

May be help you to get idea for you problem